# How do i stop my family set up because i dont have a family

Tags: 7.8

Must I set up my family account before downloading any app on my Microsoft store?

Comment: Why are still on 7.8??

Comment: Why wouldn't he? Not like you can upgrade old phones to 8.0/8.1

Comment: @RamRaj Comments are supposed to be constructive asking clarifications, suggesting workarounds, etc... For more information see *When should I comment?* section in [this guidline](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: okay, i get it !!!